# "Get Programming With Haskell" error in the first code example

Tags: haskell

i'm reading "Get Programming With Haskell" and the second lesson is to write and compile this simple code

```
toPart rec = "Dear " ++ rec ++ " \n"
bodyPart bookT = "Thanks for buying " ++ bookT ++" \n"
fromPart auth = "thanks \n " ++ auth


createEmail rec bookT auth
= toPart rec ++

bodyPart bookT ++

fromPart auth
```

but i'm get this error from GHCI

```
Prelude> :l first_prog.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( first_prog.hs, interpreted )

first_prog.hs:7:5: error:
    parse error on input ‘=’
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'
  |
7 | let = toPart rec ++
  |     ^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

the author did not explain any thing about the syntax yet so i don't know where is the error here

Comment: You shoud not add a new line here, or at least not without proper indentation `createEmail rec bookT auth = toPart rec ++ bodyPart bookT ++ fromPart auth` should solve the issue.

Comment: i think i read an amazon review of the book complains about this error and how the author should have talked about indentation more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong usage of *spaces* and *indentation* can cause problems in Haskell. In the code,you can try writing it in one line so that you do not get confused by the indentation. Example :

`createEmail rec bookT auth = toPart rec ++ bodyPart bookT ++ fromPart auth`

If you wanna use the style of the tutorial, what you need to do is :

```
createEmail rec bookT auth
 = toPart rec ++

 bodyPart bookT ++

 fromPart auth
```

Basically, put a space in front of each line and it should solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Haskell relies on indentation so we should fix it a little:

```
toPart rec = "Dear " ++ rec ++ " \n"
bodyPart bookT = "Thanks for buying " ++ bookT ++" \n"
fromPart auth = "thanks \n " ++ auth   

createEmail rec bookT auth
  = toPart rec ++
    bodyPart bookT ++
    fromPart auth
```

Comment: Small nitpick: strictly speaking Haskell doesn't "rely" on indentation. You can write everything with `{` and `}` around blocks of code and `;` after each "statement", and then GHC (or any Haskell compiler) will be able to parse it fine, no matter where you put your whitespace. Strictly speaking the rules for the use of whitespace are just a kind of syntactic sugar to tell the compiler where to insert the curly braces and semicolons. (This is part of the formal language specification.) But yes, almost everyone uses indentation, and for good reason - readability is important.

Answer (score 0):

```
toPart recepient = "Dear " ++ recepient ++ " \n"
bodyPart title = "Thanks for buying " ++ title ++" \n"
fromPart author = "thanks \n " ++ author   

createEmail recepient title author
  = toPart recepient ++
    bodyPart title ++
    fromPart author

main = do
print "who is the email for?"
recepient <- getLine
print "what is the title?"
title <- getLine
print "Who is the author?"
author <- getLine
print (createEmail recepient title author)
```

Comment: This is a 100% working code from the same damn book

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include a short explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful to future readers.